# Run crontab in specific day but only if is in specific weekday

Tags: cron

I wanna run command with crontab in a specific day, but only if this day is not sunday. 
I tried with this

> 1 0 27 12 1-6 command.sh

but the command run also wednesday december 26th.
How can I tell to crontab run command only the december 27th?

Thanks
Max

Comment: You want the job to run on 27 but that day must not be a sunday but can be any other day!

Comment: Try this `1 0 27 * 1-6`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen `1 0 27 * 1-6` will run on every 27th ***plus*** every Mon…Sat. Cron's syntax is mean.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it is possible with `cron` alone because the syntax doesn't
allow for *"at 27<sup>th</sup> except on Sundays"*.  It only allows
for *"either 27<sup>th</sup> or non-Sundays (or both)"*.

I suggest to either change `command.sh` to immediately exit on non-Sundays
or put that check into the *cronjob*:

```
1 0 27 12 *   test $(date +\%u) -ne 7   &&  command.sh
```

At the shell, `date +%u` returns the day of week (1…7, 1 is Monday). In
a cronjob we have to escape that `%` sign (`\%`). The command will
check whether the current day is a non-Sunday and only then execute
`command.sh`.

The cronjob will run on every Dec 27<sup>th</sup> at 00:01 o'clock,
no matter what day of the week that is, but only for non-Sundays the
`command.sh` gets executed because the previous test only succeeds
for them.

Note: I sometimes use https://crontab.guru to check my cronjob's 
timetables.  It's quite handy.
[Your definition](https://crontab.guru/#1_0_27_12_1-6) translates to *“At
00:01 on day-of-month 27 **and** on every day-of-week from Monday through
Saturday in December.”* so it's quite the opposite of what you want.

---

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/crontab.5.html):

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields
>   — day of month, and day of week.  If both fields are restricted (i.e.,
>   aren't *), the command will be run when *either* field matches the
>   current time.  For example, `30 4 1,15 * 5` would cause a command to
>   be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, *plus* every
>   Friday. One can,  however, achieve the desired result by adding a test
>   to the command (see the last example in EXAMPLE CRON FILE below).
>
> …
>
> ```
> # Run on every second Saturday of the month
> 0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
> ```

Comment: Many thanks, I hoped that cron use "or" condition not "and" condition....

Comment: @maxranzy You are welcome. Yes, when it gets more complicated than "run Y every X" and some of "but/except/and/or/not" are needed, then often some fiddling is necessary. Sometimes two or more jobs with different timetables, sometimes a test whithin the job.